# Construct a Binary Search Tree from String of Integer

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

In the class containing the main function, define a function call *createTree(String strKey)*. Giving a string of integers (separated by a space character), this function will create a BST tree with the keys of integers following the input string.
Example: Given a string s = "30 20 40". Calling the function createTree(s) to create a binary seach tree: root = 30, root.left = 20, root.right = 40.
Below is my code:

- Node.java

```java
public class Node {
    Integer key;
    Node left, right;
    
    public Node(Integer key){
        this.key = key;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}
```

- BST.java

```java
public class BST {
    
    private Node root;
    
    public BST(){
        this.root = null;
    }
    
    public Node getRoot(){
        return this.root;
    }

    public Node insert(Node x, Integer key){
        if (x == null){
            return new Node(key);
        }
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if (cmp < 0){
            x.left = insert(x.left,key);
        }
        else if (cmp > 0){
            x.right = insert(x.right,key);
        }
        else {
            x.key = key;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

- Test.java

```java
public class Test {
    
    public static BST createTree(String strKey){
        String[] spl = strKey.split(" ");
        BST tree = new BST();
        Node root = null;
        for (int i=0; i<spl.length; i++){
            Integer key = Integer.parseInt(spl[i]);
            tree.insert(root,key);
        }
        return tree;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "20 30 40";
        BST tree = createTree(s);
        System.out.println(tree.getRoot());
    }
}
```

The result is also null (the root is null) and I don't know the reason why the key is not inserted into the tree. Hope you guys can help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x == null){
    return new Node(key);
}
```

The returned node is not assigned to the *root* in the `BST` class. Also, you have a *root* in the `createTree` method.

You can change it to include an overloaded `insert` function which takes only the integer to insert and make the existing one private.

```
private Node insert(Node x, Integer key){
    //your existing code
}

public void insert(Integer key) {
    this.root = insert(this.root, key);
}
```

With this, the root will be updated when it is created the first time.

From `createTree` call the one argument `insert` method.

```
public static BST createTree(String strKey) {
    String[] spl = strKey.split(" ");
    BST tree = new BST();
    for (int i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
        Integer key = Integer.parseInt(spl[i]);
        tree.insert(key);
    }
    return tree;
}
```